# How to modify context menu dimensions in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, svg, javafx

With CSS, I was able to modify everything but the size of a ChoiceBox's
ContextMenu object. The background color, the highlight color, the position in the window, and the check mark color. The top picture is of a native Mac application (which I'm trying to achieve the style of), and the bottom picture is my JavaFX application. I need the drop-down menu to match the native one exactly.

[image: native]

[image: JavaFX]

Also, if possible, can the Context-Menu check marks be modified shape-wise? I was able to create a custom SVG for the CheckBox mark.

Comment: As you are trying to mimic native OS X controls, maybe you should try [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com), which is "The native Mac OS X skin for your JavaFX application".

Comment: @jewelsea I already did. As far as I could tell it was never updated for the Yosemite / El Capitan L&F. But thanks, because they still probably found a way to modify all the necessary stuff so I can check their stylesheets!

Comment: Never mind AquaFX didn't manage to modify the context menu size either. And AquaFX looks ugly. I even managed to replicate the native L&F better than that with custom SVG's and effects.